# Configurating the Width of Columns in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to adjust width of one of the columns in Django Admin so I found several answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182303/how-to-wrap-text-in-django-adminset-column-width) but it didn't solve my issue

Is this the best way to do it? if not what is another better solution?

here is the admin.py

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id','design']

    class Media:
        css = ('/css/fancy.css'.format(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0]+ '/css/fancy.css'),)
```

here is the fancy.css

```
.column-design {
    width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That CSS rule should work. I suspect the issue is with your `PostAdmin.Media.css` value, which doesn't seem to quite match the structure that [the docs describe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions). (Also you normally don't need to include the `settings.STATICFILES_DIR` value.)

I think it might work if you re-arrange your code like this:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id','design']

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': (
                '/css/fancy.css',
            )
        }
```